# AttributeError: 'Event' object has no attribute 'button'

Tags: python, pygame

Here's my Code and I am just trying run my xbox controller for later on if statements to control dc motors:

```
pygame.init()
joystick = []
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

for i in range(0, pygame.joystick.get_count()):
    joystick.append(pygame.joystick.Joystick(i))
    joystick[-1].init()
        
while True:
    clock.tick(60)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.button == 0:
            print ("A Has Been Pressed")
        elif event.button == 1:
            print ("B Has Been Pressed")
        elif event.button == 2:
            print ("X Has Been Pressed")
        elif event.button == 3:
            print ("Y Has Been Pressed")
```

I get the error message below when I run my code:

```
pygame 1.9.4.post1
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
A Has Been Pressed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Documents/Code/Practice.py", line 13, in <module>
    if event.button == 0:
AttributeError: 'Event' object has no attribute 'button'
```

Comment: Is the issue solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each event type generates a [`pygame.event.Event`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html) object with different attributes. The `button` attribute is not defined for all event objects. You can just get the `button` attribute from a mouse or joystick event like `MOUSEMOTION` or `MOUSEBUTTONDOWN`. However all event objects have a `type` attribute. Check the event `type` attribute before the `button` attribute (see [`pygame.event`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html)):

```py
while True:
    clock.tick(60)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if event.button == 0:
                print ("A Has Been Pressed")
            elif event.button == 1:
                print ("B Has Been Pressed")
            elif event.button == 2:
                print ("X Has Been Pressed")
            elif event.button == 3:
                print ("Y Has Been Pressed")
```

The `MOUSEBUTTONDOWN` event occurs once when you click the mouse button and the `MOUSEBUTTONUP` event occurs once when the mouse button is released. The [`pygame.event.Event()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.Event) object has two attributes that provide information about the mouse event. `pos` is a tuple that stores the position that was clicked. `button` stores the button that was clicked. Each mouse button is associated a value. For instance the value of the attributes is 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 for the left mouse button, middle mouse button, right mouse button, mouse wheel up respectively mouse wheel down. When multiple keys are pressed, multiple mouse button events occur.